# How to inverse the distance formula in 3d?

Tags: vector-spaces, 3d

I know how to output the distance between two points in space, but how can I reverse it? Instead of outputing a small value for somethink close I want to outpun a big value, and instead of a value big for somethink far I want to output a small value. I want them to range from 0 (even one if it is the only way) and a max value called a.

My reasons: I make a 3D pathfinding and I try to make a proximity area, further point from object will have a lower value.

Comment: @PinkPanther that would diverge. He wants something finite ("a max value called a")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the regular distance is $d$, try $d_{new}=a e^{-d}$. When $d=0$ you get $d_{new}=a$ and when $d\to\infty$ you get $d_{new}\to 0$. Other options would be inverse cotangent.

**Edited** I've changed $d'$ to $d_{new}$ to avoid confusing it with derivative

Comment: I never think derivation will help me at all. Thanks you

Comment: Beside that, could you explain what formula you used? I never rememberd of smth like this in school

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It's not a derivative, it's just d prime. I could have used $f$ or something. I will change it in the reply. I did not use any formula. I just remembered the image of functions. You want a decreasing function from $0$ to $\infty$, but with a finite range. $e^{-d^2}$ would also work.